# axios vs fetch - when making an api call

Tags: react-redux, fetch, axios

Which do you prefer and did you see any benefits using axios - when we can use a normal fetch while making api calls? Did any one had to change to axios for any specific use case?

Answer (score 2):

Overall they are very similar. Some benefits of axios:

Transformers: allow performing transforms on data before request is made or after response is received

Interceptors: allow you to alter the request or response entirely (headers as well). also perform async operations before request is made or before Promise settles

Built-in XSRF protection

To get more answers, please visit this link.
[what advantage does axios give us over fetch](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/314)

Comment: What builtin XSRF?  I am getting a CORS error on a simple GET which completely confuses me.  It is a django backend that I know has allow all CORS through.  What is really maddening was that it worked at one point and now does not.  But Is see no evidence that axios is doing anything good in this area.